# Setting template header to text/xml in Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento

I have stats.phtml which is a dynamic XML file.

I added `<?php header("Content-type: text/xml"); ?>` on the beginning of the file, but for some reason the page still has `text/html` header.

The layout definition for that page:

```
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="stats/stats" name="stats" template="stats/stats.phtml" />
    </reference>
```

Any way I could set the correct header for XML template?

Comment: `header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');` and in content `<?xml version="1.0"?>`?

Comment: the same result, no header changed with this

Answer (score 0):

That is because your header content type is already being set by `page/html/head.phtml`

You have to add you customer head which define your custom header content type in this way

copy `page/html/head.phtml` and rename to `page/html/head2.phtml`

Modify you content type in `head2.phtml`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xml" />
```

and then add this code in your layout xml

```
<reference name="head">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/head2.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="stats/stats" name="stats" template="stats/stats.phtml" />
</reference>
```

So it will replace existing `head.phtml` with your custom `head2.phtml`